# SiteProfileNotAvailable error

Tags: python, django

I know same question being asked many times. I have successfully setup all things. I didn't get this error when i run this on localhost. But when i run the site on deployment server i got this error not always but very often. When i refresh page 3 or 4 times the error disappears but keeps on coming again and again which is very annoying.

My directory structure related to problem is as:

- project (folder)

  - profiles (folder)

    - models.py (file)
  - settings.py (file)

I have folder `profiles`in which there is `models.py` and i have class `Profile` there.
In `settings.py` i have included `profiles` folder to my apps also and i have set `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.Profile'`.

Also in Profile class i have added the path for application:

```
class Profile(UserenaLanguageBaseProfile):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'profiles'
```

Can any one help me to figure out this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `Django 1.4 trunck` version, after upgrading the package again that problem is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE should be a string:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.Profile'
```