# Django userena raises SiteProfileNotAvailable unpredictably

Tags: django, apache

My project uses userena, which in some place called django.db.models.get_model.
It is uses for getting profile model, which places in profiles.Profile. It is in INSTALLED_APPS, so it should returns fine, but sometimes (seems unpredictable, mostly after apache restart) get_model returns None for this model (profiles.Profile). And userena raises SiteProfileNotAvailable error.

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.Profile'
```

At first I thought userena passes wrong parameters to the get_model, but I double check this and it is really passes app_label='profile' and model_name='Profile'.

Then I tried to open python manage.py shell, import get_model and call it:       `get_model('profile', 'Profile')`
 and it returns valid Profile model. I exited from shell and after doing this, site magically do work. But after apache restart it is again raises the  same error. Maybe this action updated cache, I don't know.

On my local machine it is never happened, so I think it's somehow connected with apache.

---

UPDATE: The problem was django1.4-alpha version. After updating to lates version bug is gone.

Comment: I also has the same issue and didn't get fixed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841353/siteprofilenotavailable-error :(

Comment: Thinking of the environment issue I moved the site to mod_python instead of mod_wsgi. The error never appears for some weeks now its again punching me.

Comment: The problem was django1.4-alpha version. After updating to lates version bug is gone.

Comment: as today apparently still there in django 1.7 https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/issues/432